# Understanding spark-sbt-plugin

Tags: apache-spark, sbt-plugin

I came across this detailed explanation on how to setup [`build.sbt` for Spark](https://hadoopist.wordpress.com/2016/08/09/creat-a-simple-build-sbt-file-for-a-spark-project/).

But then I read about the [SBT plugin for Spark packages](https://github.com/databricks/sbt-spark-package) where apparently a single line like

```
https://github.com/databricks/sbt-spark-package
```

is OK as the plugin is doing the nasty work.

Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes. If you take a look at a simple .sbt file used for Spark (e.g., https://github.com/databricks/learning-spark/blob/master/build.sbt), you can see that you'll need to include a bunch of spark dependencies. (ok, not all the ones listed there...).

In addition, if you look at what the plugin does, you will find some more utility functions: https://github.com/databricks/sbt-spark-package/blob/master/src/main/scala/sbtsparkpackage/SparkPackagePlugin.scala

It's a cool plugin!